# sencha touch + phonegap native app stuck on loading blue screen

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I have built a  app with sencha touch 2.3 and cmd 4 and  then successfully  make native android app with both sencha cmd and phonegap. but in both cases my app  remain on the blue loading screen with 3 dots on it nothing else.

then i try it with simple app generated by "sencha app generate" command but the result remain same.
please help  me , i have no idea where is the error.

this is my android emulator log file

```
I/ActivityManager(   60): Displayed activity com.android.launcher/com.android.la
uncher2.Launcher: 111139 ms (total 111139 ms)
D/dalvikvm(  118): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1042 objects / 53400 bytes in 108ms
I/ActivityManager(   60): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.
MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.phonegap.www/
.PGBuildApp }
I/ActivityManager(   60): Start proc com.phonegap.www for activity com.phonegap.
www/.PGBuildApp: pid=238 uid=10036 gids={3003, 1006, 1015}
D/dalvikvm(  238): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1720 objects / 158456 bytes in 150ms
I/dalvikvm(  238): Could not find method org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.setOv
erScrollMode, referenced from method org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.init
W/dalvikvm(  238): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2486: Lorg/apache/cordo
va/CordovaWebView;.setOverScrollMode (I)V
D/dalvikvm(  238): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0043
I/CordovaLog(  238): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
D/CordovaActivity(  238): CordovaActivity.onCreate()
I/dalvikvm(  238): Could not find method android.webkit.WebView.<init>, referenc
ed from method org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.<init>
W/dalvikvm(  238): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 345: Landroid/webkit/Web
View;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;IZ)V
D/dalvikvm(  238): VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0001
D/dalvikvm(  238): VFY: dead code 0x0004-0046 in Lorg/apache/cordova/CordovaWebV
iew;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;IZ)V
D/CordovaWebView(  238): CordovaWebView is running on device made by: unknown
D/JsMessageQueue(  238): Set native->JS mode to 2
I/CordovaWebView(  238): Disabled addJavascriptInterface() bridge since Android
version is old.
D/CordovaActivity(  238): CordovaActivity.init()
 D/CordovaWebView(  238): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
D/PluginManager(  238): init()
D/CordovaWebView(  238): >>> loadUrlNow()
D/Config  (  238): Unlimited access to network resources
I/CordovaLog(  238): Found start page location: index.html
I/CordovaLog(  238): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
D/CordovaActivity(  238): Resuming the App
D/CordovaActivity(  238): CB-3064: The errorUrl is null
D/SoftKeyboardDetect(  238): Ignore this event
D/SoftKeyboardDetect(  238): Ignore this event
I/ActivityManager(   60): Displayed activity com.phonegap.www/.PGBuildApp: 4678
ms (total 4678 ms)
I/ARMAssembler(   60): generated scanline__00000077:03545404_00000004_00000000 [
47 ipp] (67 ins) at [0x52f610:0x52f71c] in 1011887 ns
D/CordovaActivity(  238): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/inde
x.html)
D/Cordova (  238): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
D/CordovaActivity(  238): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/ind
ex.html)
D/CordovaActivity(  238): onMessage(spinner,stop)
D/dalvikvm(  118): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1084 objects / 61000 bytes in 4348ms
```

Comment: Any errors in the chrome console?

Comment: thanx @DarinKolev for reply
no, there is no error in chrome console.
sencha project running fine in chrome and safari but 
problem is occurring  with android app with sencha project